# How to control concurrency in SQL Server SELECT queries?

Tags: sql, sql-server, concurrency, transactions, acid

How to control concurrency in SQL Server SELECT queries?

Here is the problem, these SQL queries below are going to execute at the same time but they should not take the same record.

How could I handle this?

**Session 1:**

```
BEGIN TRAN

DECLARE @Id INT

SELECT TOP 1 @Id = Id 
FROM dbo.Table_1

UPDATE dbo.Table_1
SET is_taken = 1
WHERE Id = @Id

COMMIT TRAN
```

**Session 2:**

```
BEGIN TRAN

DECLARE @Id INT

SELECT TOP 1 @Id = Id 
FROM dbo.Table_1

UPDATE dbo.Table_1
SET is_taken = 1
WHERE Id = @Id

COMMIT TRAN
```

Comment: Whats you isolation setting?

Comment: What do you mean they shouldn't take the same record? You are using top 1 but there is no order by so there is no guarantee which row you will get back.

Comment: They won't ever be able to update the same record - even if they both get the same `@id` value. If #1 gets the update lock on the row with `@Id`, then #2 cannot start the update - it'll have to wait until #1 is done.

Comment: @MarvinSmit
Acutally I don't really know anything about them, I tried to use RowLock, ReadPast and ... but I couldn't get any results.

Comment: unless you have an isolation level of dirty read or lower, this should already have sufficient isolation for your mentioned functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, SQL Server takes care of isolation, hence you can just run update without select:

```
UPDATE TOP (1) dbo.Table_1
SET is_taken = 1
```

I guess you meant to also have a condition on select to avoid updating same record each time:

```
UPDATE TOP (1) dbo.Table_1
SET is_taken = 1
OUTPUT INSERTED.Id into @id
WHERE is_taken != 1
```

Comment: What's the best ISOLATION level for this?

Comment: READ COMMITTED is all you neeed

Comment: It doesn't work. It just reduces the probability. How update works: at first you need to find a row by condition WHERE is_taken != 1. When UPDATE searching a row which should be updated it allowed for other queries to read this table. It means that it's possible that two requests will return the same result.

Answer (score 1):

You can lock the row that you are updating which would have session 2 wait until the transaction in session 1 is completed. 
I would consider using an update lock or a shared lock(read only).

This should eliminate any concerns you have concurrency between session.

[Understand Locking in SQL Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213039(v=sql.80).aspx)